# C# mouse_event while holding left mouse button

Tags: c#

so I have this code and it is currently working, however, it does not work how I want it to. I would like it so if my LEFT mouse button is held, then it repeatedly clicks, however, I am using mouse_event and simulating mouse up which causes it to only click once maybe twice and then stop as it thinks that I released the mouse button...

```
const int leftDown = 0x0002;
const int leftUp = 0x0004;
const int leftIsDown = 0x01;
while (true)

  if (Settings.bClicker && (Utils.GetAsyncKeyState(leftIsDown) & 0x8000) > 0)
  {
    Utils.mouse_event(leftDown, 0, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    Utils.mouse_event(leftUp,   0, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

Any ideas? It works with say, right mouse button being held but not left ;(

Comment: I edited the code to make it readable, now the bug ought to be a lot more obvious.  And the new bug you'll get when you fix it.

Comment: Well, I see the bug just not sure how to to fix it.

Comment: Nobody knows how to fix it.  You'll need more cheese.

Comment: welp that sucks